# multi vs one prediction using Regression

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, data-science

I was trying to build a prediction system where I have the input data arranged in multiple columns. The input data would be of the type where I have

- weather,
- service type (bronze, silver, gold),
- size (xs, s, m, l, xl, xxl),
- time,
- availability,
- pin code, and
- the result (target).

Each of the data types is arranged in columns with a specific code. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48385376/3924118), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33369706/3924118), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44613753/3924118) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29625263/3924118), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3712863/3924118).

They are helpful but do not give me a clear picture. I would like to achieve a multi-vs-one prediction. Most of the schemes available are one-vs-one where the data is a 1*1 entity.

Here is a sample code that I was working with:

```
regressionModel = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    """ 3. Processing is not necessary for current concept """
    y = pd.DataFrame(modifiedDFSet['Code'])
    print(y.shape)
    drop2 = ['Code']
    X = modifiedDFSet.drop(drop2)
    print(X.shape)
    """ 4. Data Scaling, Data Imputation is not necessary. Training and Test data is prepared using train-test-split """
    train_data, test_data = train_test_split(X, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)
    """ 5. the Regression Model """
    # h = .02  # step size in the mesh
    # logreg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    # we create an instance of Neighbours Classifier and fit the data.
    regressionModel.fit(X, y)
    d_predictions = regressionModel.predict(y)
```

`X.shape` and `y.shape` would yield `(500, 6)` and `(500, 1)`, respectively, which would obviously cause a dimensional error in the `d_predictions`, meaning the regression model does not take multiple column inputs.

I have a hypothesis that I can create a scoring scheme that will take into account the importance of each of the columns and create a scheme that creates a score and the end result would be a one-vs-one regression problem. **Looking for some direction with respect to my hypothesis. Is it correct, wrong or halfway?**

Comment: Welcome to Ai.se...to clarify your question, are you using certain software?

Comment: No. I do not want to use any tool or software. I intend to hardcode using python 3x.  I am open to exploring new libraries. I am using scikit learn at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I think the model will have no problem taking a multicolumn input. In fact, from your code, this is exactly how you trained it. It expects an input of size [k, 6], where k is k>=1.

Instead you are feeding it with [k, 1] sized data, which are the dimensions of *y*. So you if you run it like this it should work:

regressionModel.predict(X)